# Get multiple columns in WHERE clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, select, where-clause

I want to have 3 columns in the where clause, I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT ImageID FROM [ImageWithTags] WHERE Tag1=@TAG1, Tag2=@TAG2, Tag3=@TAG3
```

How can I get the output for the above?

I want all three columns for my c# application, I've tried several ways but couldn't find the correct one.

Comment: `Tag1=@TAG1 And Tag2=@Tag2 etc...` or `Tag1=@TAG1 Or Tag2=@TAG2 etc.`

Comment: _"Get multiple columns in WHERE clause"_  doesn't really make sense. You seem to want to select one column where three conditions apply. You either want _any_ of those conditions to be true (use `OR`), or all of them (use `AND`), or a combination thereof (use `a AND b OR c`).

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
SELECT ImageID FROM [ImageWithTags] WHERE Tag1=@TAG1 OR Tag2=@TAG2 OR Tag3=@TAG3"
```

And if you want just the rows that satisfy all of those tags than:

```
SELECT ImageID FROM [ImageWithTags] WHERE Tag1=@TAG1 AND Tag2=@TAG2 AND Tag3=@TAG3"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ImageID FROM [ImageWithTags] WHERE Tag1=@TAG1 AND Tag2=@TAG2 AND Tag3=@TAG3
```